# How to insert smalldatetime value to data base column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one from user table like :

```
Id  int Unchecked
Name    varchar(50) Checked
EmailAddress    varchar(200)    Unchecked
Host    varchar(250)    Unchecked
Port    int Unchecked
POPHost varchar(250)    Checked
POPPort int Checked
Password    varchar(50) Unchecked
CreatedDate smalldatetime   Unchecked
user_id int Unchecked
EnableSSL   bit Unchecked
Count   int Unchecked
SentDateTime    smalldatetime   Checked
MaxCount    int Checked
```

and this is stored-proc for updating specific field as per selection like :

```
USE [EASYMAIL]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateFromUserField]    Script Date: 20/02/2017 8:35:24 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateFromUserField]
(
    @fromuser_id int,
    @var_name varchar(25),
    @var_value varchar(100)
)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     IF @var_name = 'Name'
        UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_From_master]  SET [Name] =CAST(@var_value AS TEXT) WHERE (Id=@fromuser_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'EmailAddress'
        UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_From_master] SET [EmailAddress] = CAST(@var_value AS TEXT) WHERE (Id=@fromuser_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'Host'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_From_master] SET [Host] = CAST(@var_value AS TEXT) WHERE (Id=@fromuser_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'Port'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_From_master] SET [Port]  = CAST(@var_value AS INT) WHERE (Id = @fromuser_id)
        ELSE IF @var_name = 'POPHost'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_From_master] SET [POPHost] = CAST(@var_value AS TEXT) WHERE (Id=@fromuser_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'POPPort'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_From_master] SET [POPPort]  = CAST(@var_value AS INT) WHERE (Id = @fromuser_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'EnableSSL'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_From_master] SET [EnableSSL]  = CAST(@var_value AS BIT) WHERE (Id = @fromuser_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'SentDateTime'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_From_master] SET [SentDateTime]  = SUBSTRING(@var_value,4,3) + LEFT(@var_value,3) + RIGHT(@var_value,4) WHERE (Id = @fromuser_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'Count' 
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_From_master]  SET [Count] = CAST (@var_value AS INT) WHERE (Id=@fromuser_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'MaxCount' 
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_From_master]  SET [MaxCount] = CAST (@var_value AS INT) WHERE (Id=@fromuser_id)
END
```

However, it's getting an error on executing time like:

```
USE [EASYMAIL]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[UpdateFromUserField]
        @fromuser_id = 1,
        @var_name = N'SentDateTime',
        @var_value = N'2017-02-20 8:32:12'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Error :

```
Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Procedure UpdateFromUserField, Line 26
Conversion failed when converting a character string to smalldatetime data type.
```

What could be the mistake here? 
please help me

**Updated**

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Source Error: 


Line 618:   public int UpdateFromUserField([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> fromuser_id, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="VarChar(25)")] string var_name, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="VarChar(100)")] string var_value)
Line 619:   {
Line 620:       IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), fromuser_id, var_name, var_value);
Line 621:       return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
Line 622:   }

Source File: e:\EASYMAIL_off\EASYMAIL\App_Code\DataClasses.designer.cs    Line: 620
```

Comment: It seems the only place where you set a date is: `SET [SentDateTime]  = SUBSTRING(@var_value,4,3) + LEFT(@var_value,3) + RIGHT(@var_value,4)`

Comment: this gives me err as : Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
SET [SentDateTime] = SUBSTRING(@var_value,4,3) + LEFT(@var_value,3) + RIGHT(@var_value,4)
```

By:

```
SET [SentDateTime] = CAST(LEFT(@var_value,4) + SUBSTRING(@var_value,6,2) + SUBSTRING(@var_value,9,2)) AS SMALLDATETIME)
```

Or:

```
SET [SentDateTime] = CAST(@var_vaule AS SMALLDATETIME)
```

Comment: It's give me error like : The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I call that procedure this way can u examine :  'db.UpdateFromUserField(fromuserid, "SentDateTime", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString());'

Comment: It's give me this error : The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Stored Procedure working fine but gives Project error see updated linqtosql statement.

Comment: ok. Here is code : db.UpdateFromUserField(fromuserid, "SentDateTime", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString()); here last DateTime.Now value is assignment to stored proc @var_value

Comment: Are you always using .Now() ?   Change you SP just to use GETDATE() instead of pass a parameter